# EMF-JSON: Include properties of EObject Subclass

Tags: jackson, emf

I am using [EMF-JSON](http://emfjson.org/) for serializing an EMF model instance. The problem is, that a subclass of EObject gets treated as such and not as the subclass. Thus, properties in the subclass get lost during serialization, as the EObjectSerializer is selected. How can I make sure that the properties of the subclass are included without changing the class itself (referring to the inclusion annotations)? In the following you find the generated interfaces. In this case, the ***ref*** property of the ***ArithVar*** class is not serialized.

```
public interface ArithExpr extends EObject {}

public interface ArithVar extends ArithExpr {
    VarType getRef();
    void setRef(VarType value);
}

public interface VarType extends EObject {}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://emfjson.org/projects/jackson/latest/):

> References are by default serialized as JSON objects that contain two fields. The first field is the type of the referenced object and the second field is the URI of the referenced object. The type field is named eClass and the URI field is named $ref.

So my guess is it *should* work by default. Have you tried debugging through EObjectSerializer ? My guess is it probably uses the EMF reflective API to iterate through all the features of an EObject and serialize them.

Comment: Then the question would be how to set up the referenced object? In fact, the eClass and $ref properties are set in the JSON string. However, creating the EObject from that again results in the empty object.